# Custom week number of year for school

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, operators, momentjs

I'm trying to display the school semester week number by modifying the iso week number.

Comment: As the message indicates, you have a syntax error. `if (weekNo >= 5 && <= 18 ){`

Comment: all answers are good, but if you want the intent of your conditional to be more obvious you can always write the conditional like `if (5 <= weekNo && weekNo <= 18)` - which clearly shows that it's checking for weekNo between those ranges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot compare a number to multiple values like that

```
if (weekNo >= 5 && <= 18)
```

is illegal syntax. instead you make two comparisons joined with a "logical and" operator: `&&`

```
if (weekNo >= 5 && weekNo <= 18)
```

This says: "if weekNo is greater than or equal to 5" AND "if weekNo is less than or equal to 18"

Answer (score 3):

Each side of the `&&` operator is considered a separate statement for evaluation. It is expecting an identifier after the `&&`.

Rewrite it like this for each of your `if` statements:

```
weekNo >= 5 && weekNo <= 18
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some formatting as others have pointed out and there is a rogue comma bewfore the return statement. I have formatted your block for you.

```js
function getWeekNumber(d) {
    // Copy date so don't modify original
    d = new Date(+d);
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
    // Make Sunday's day number 7
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay()||7));
    // Get first day of year
    var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(),0,1);
    // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
    var weekNo = Math.ceil((( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7);
    // Return array of year and week number


    //modify week number to display 1-12 semester 2
    if (weekNo >= 5 && weekNo <= 18 ) {
        var schoolWeekNo = weekNo - 4;
        var semester = 2;
    }
    //modify week number to display 1-12 semester 1
    else if (weekNo >= 39 && weekNo<= 50) {
        var schoolWeekNo = weekNo - 38;
        var semester = 1;
    }
    //do not display week number for none semester dates
    else {
        schoolWeekNo = null;
        semester = null;
    };
    return [semester,schoolWeekNo];

};

alert(getWeekNumber(Date.now()));
```